# How do I hide firebug's bottom console from non-console tabs? E.g. hide console below HTML tab

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, firebug

This has been frustrating me for a while... When I right clicked a CSS rule in the **Computed** tab and then cliked "**Use in Command Line**", this opened up a special bottom console that has no close button or any other button to rehide it. The screenshot shows a red button at the left corner, but this just shows the history of previous commands:

[image: Firebug console in HTML tab]

The little down-arrow-triangle on the current tab does not allow to expand the tab to full height either, the only tab that this bottom console does not show up is the [**Console** tab](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Options_Menu).

The only way I found to circumvent/minimize this problem is to reduce the size of this bottom console. Still, it doesn't make much sense to do this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### This opened up a console that has no close button or any other button to hide it.

It's a "Command Line Popup".

To show/hide it click on the "Show Command Line Popup" button [image] which is a toggle:

[image]

---

#### Command Line

> The Command Line is also available in other panels through the Command Line Popup Button ( [image: CommandLinePopupButton.png] ). To see the output of the commands you have to drag the resizer above the Command Line Popup.

Source [Command Line](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Firebug Wiki](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: LOL! Really appreciated David, went through a lot of firebug options and thought there should be a simple way to hide it, but never dreamed it was that simple... Only your highlighting made me notice there was something there... It kind of makes sense now xD

Comment: @Armfoot You are very welcome ;)